# TeXstudio cannot see .dic files

Tags: texstudio

I want to add a dictionary to TeXstudio (`.dic/.aff`). Here are the files in my visual file explorer:

[image]

And here's the same folder when trying to select the files in TeXstudio:

[image]

What is this sorcery? Where are the `.dic` and `.aff` files? "Show hidden files" is on.

Comment: Your explorer screen, ask for a directory not a file. Could it be that the program with the directory indication will read the 'dic' files it contains?

Comment: You're right! Selecting the directory containing the `.dic` and `.aff` files loaded them correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to "Import Dictionaries", a different button in TeXstudio > Configure TeXstudio > Language Checking, which successfully loaded a `.oxt` file, though not the desired `.dic/.aff` files in the original question.

EDIT: Please see also the comment on the question.

Comment: What about: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401556/texstudio-cannot-see-dic-files?rq=1#comment1000314_401556